# How to rename a colum using code first and linq to entities

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I created a column very quickly with code first and linq to entities, but I no longer like the name and would like to change it. However, I am unsure of what the best way to do this might be?

For example, can I rename it on my class and the database will auto update?

Should I rename it by hand in both the class and the database?

Is there an even better magical way to do this using code first migrations?

Comment: Are you using visual studio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using code first so you will change the column name in your class and then in the package manage console you run `add-migration [name]` (name is optional and if omitted you will be prompted), that will generate a migration with an `Up` and `Down` method (these allow for the changes to be applied and support a rollback), you then apply that to your database using `update-database`

Do not update your database directly if using code first as EF will not like it, also ensure your Data project is selected in the package manager console

Comment: Are you sure that this does not generate Create/Drop column? I can't remember where but I read that column rename si not generated by add-migration... I read that you should insert RenameColumn in Up (same in Down) manually.